# How can I call this method in another activity?

Tags: java, android

In my main Activity, I have this method:

```
 public void CancelAlarms() {

            AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
            manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
```

but I want to call it in my other activity.

How can I call it from one activity to another? Also, would it be alright if I am using context in the method? Would the context change if I call it from another activity to this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably move this method to a utility class or to a base `Activity` class, for exactly the reason you mention:  it depends on a `Context`.

You simply *won't* be able to invoke this method without having a reference to an instance of the Activity it is in, because it is not marked `static`.  And even if you did, it would use its host `Activity`--probably not what you intend.

Instead, you could make a utility class containing the method.  There are two ways to go about this:  you could pass the `Context` in to the function every time, or you could pass a `Context` once to the class's constructor.  The former is probably better for one-off convenience methods grouped into a `Utilities` class, while the latter is a bit more Java-like and is better if the class has a definite function (like an `ActivityAlarmWrangler`).

Finally, you could move the function to a base class.  This will be cleanest for simple cases because you don't have to have a different member object in your `Activity`, but if your `Activity` already extends a custom superclass, you won't be able to use this method unless you are willing to modify the superclass.  Because Java doesn't have multiple inheritance (which would be useful in this case), inheriting this method could get hairy fairly quickly.

Comment: If I create a new base activity and have main activity and my other activity extend from it, how do I make sure I'm passing in the right context to the base activity?

Comment: It will happen automatically... Inheritance makes the method "appear" in each subclass.  An `Activity` is a type (subclass) of `Context`, so you can just pass `this` when you need to pass a `Context`.  Subclasses of `Activity`, such as your base activity, can also be cast to a `Context`.  For example, you might write (in the base class) `Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);`.

Comment: ohh thank you. Actually, I was thinking I might have needed MainActivity's context vs. my OtherActivity context which is where I am calling it right now. However, since I have all the necessary info like the pending intent inside cancel alarms, it should just cancel all alarms with that intent when I set it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make `public void CancelAlarms()` available in all Activity then create a Base Activity class implement this method in that Activity now extend all your Activity with Base Activity class than you can call this method from any Activity which has extended with Base Activity. Or put `public void CancelAlarms()` method in Application class. Now using `getApplicationContext()` you can call this method in Any Activity or Service.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a static instance of/in main activity.**

static MainActivity mainActivity;

**Initialize it in oncreate method**

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(....);
        mainActivity= this;
    }

**and make a method which returns this instance.**

public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return mainActivity;
    }

**Now from other activity you can simply call your method as following :**

MainActivity.getInstance().CancelAlarms();